# Not able to get the XML DOM parsed data on Main thread of process

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, import

I am not getting the desired output from the code.

I used XML DOM parsing to fetch title, pubdate, description and image from link: http://autosportsindia.com/feed

Through the code written no output is obtained. Even though Logcat shows that data is being fetched from the link.

Kindly tell me what is the fault in my code. Suggest any other method of XML parsing with code or link.

```
public class  MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ResultsCallBack {

PlaceholderFragment taskFragment;
ListView articlesListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        taskFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(taskFragment, "MyFragment").commit();

    } else {
        taskFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
    }
    taskFragment.startTask();

    articlesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.articlesListView);

}

@Override
public void onPreExecute() {

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results) {

    articlesListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, results));
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    AutoSportsIndia downloadTask;
    ResultsCallBack callBack;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        callBack = (ResultsCallBack) activity;

        if(downloadTask!=null)
        {
            downloadTask.onAttach(callBack);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void startTask() {
        if (downloadTask != null) {
            downloadTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            downloadTask = new AutoSportsIndia(callBack);
            downloadTask.execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callBack = null;
        if(downloadTask!=null) {
            downloadTask.onDetach();
        }

    }
}


public static class AutoSportsIndia extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    ResultsCallBack callBack =null;

    public AutoSportsIndia(ResultsCallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;

    }

    public void onAttach(ResultsCallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;

    }

    public void onDetach() {
        callBack = null;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if(callBack!=null)
        {
            callBack.onPreExecute();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String downloadURL = "http://autosportsindia.com/feed";
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(downloadURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            processXML(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            L.m(e + "");
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        if(callBack!=null)
        {
            callBack.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> processXML(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element rootElement = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
        L.m("" + rootElement.getTagName());
        NodeList itemsList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
        NodeList itemChildren = null;
        Node currentItem = null;
        Node currentChild = null;
        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> currentMap = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.getLength(); i++) {

            currentItem = itemsList.item(i);
            itemChildren = currentItem.getChildNodes();

            currentMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                currentChild = itemChildren.item(j);
                if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {

                    currentMap.put("title", currentChild.getTextContent());
                   String temp="title: "+currentChild.getTextContent();
                   L.m(temp);
             }
             if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {

                   String temp1="pubDate: "+currentChild.getTextContent();
                 currentMap.put("pubDate", currentChild.getTextContent());
                   L.m(temp1);
             }

             if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {

                 currentMap.put("description", currentChild.getTextContent());
                   String temp="description: "+currentChild.getTextContent();
                   L.m(temp);
             }
             if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 2) {
                        L.m(currentChild.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());
                        currentMap.put("imageURL", currentChild.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());
                    }
                }

                if (currentMap != null && !currentMap.isEmpty()) {
                    results.add(currentMap);
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        return results;
    }

}

}

interface ResultsCallBack {
    public void onPreExecute();

    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results);
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataSource = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataSource) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataSource.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataSource.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    MyHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
       row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
        holder = new MyHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
         holder = (MyHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    HashMap<String, String> currentItem = dataSource.get(position);
    holder.articleTitleText.setText(currentItem.get("title"));
    holder.articlePublishedDateText.setText(currentItem.get("pubDate"));
   // holder.articleImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(currentItem.get("imageURL")));
    holder.articleDescriptionText.setText(currentItem.get("description"));

    return row;
}
}

class MyHolder {
    TextView articleTitleText;

    TextView articlePublishedDateText;

    ImageView articleImage;

TextView articleDescriptionText;

public MyHolder(View view) {

articleTitleText = (TextView) 

view.findViewById(R.id.articleTitleText);

articlePublishedDateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.articlePublishedDate);


    articleImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.articleImage);

    articleDescriptionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.articleDescriptionText);
}

}
```

XML pages:-

- activity_main.xml

  ```
  <ListView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/articlesListView"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
  ```
- custom_view.xml

  ```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/articleTitleText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:padding="12dp"
      android:text="Title"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      android:textColor="#444"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/articlePublishedDate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/articleTitleText"
      android:paddingBottom="4dp"
      android:paddingLeft="12dp"
      android:paddingRight="12dp"
      android:paddingTop="4dp"
      android:text="Date"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textColor="#444"/>

  <View
      android:id="@+id/separator1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/articlePublishedDate"
      android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
      android:background="#e67e22"/>

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/articleImage"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/articleDescriptionText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/articleImage"
      android:padding="12dp"
      android:text="Description"
      android:textColor="#444"/>
  ```

Comment: Please minimize your code to show *only* the problem you're having. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code, stepping through and seeing the values being processed?

Comment: yes i have tried. Problem is in

Comment: onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results)

Comment: That method has 1 line of code. Nope, 2 lines of code. So what is the problem with that 1 or 2 lines of code?

Comment: on debugging it showed Hashmap<String,String> result : size=0

Answer (score 0):

The `processXML` method builds and returns an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.

It is called in the `doInBackground` method, but the return value is discarded. `doInBackground` then returns a local `results` object, which is an empty list.

If you had debugged your way through the `processXML` and `doInBackground` methods, you would have seen this. When I asked in a comment whether "you tried debugging your code, stepping through and seeing the values being processed", you obviously didn't.

Comment: can you just give better code to parse the link i have posted.I would be highly grateful to you.

Comment: No, I'm not going to write the code for you. I helped you find the error that was causing the list to be empty, which is the problem you said you had. If you have more problems after that, try debugging the code this time, and if you still have trouble, ask another question.

Comment: thanks @Andreas! after debugging now I code is giving proper output